# Python Sphinx Module Not Found

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a subproject that I would like to document with python sphinx.
It is structured this way:
[image]

The documentation from the extraction_model went without any problems.
But now, if I try to document the ocr part, I always get the warning:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'nfzOcr' from module 'nfz_extraction'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'helperfunc'
```

and I don't really understand why, since both are in the same directory.

helperfunc is imported this way:

```
from helperfunc import dbDeleteRow, dbInsert, dbSelect
```

and the rst would be this:

```
.. automodule:: nfz_extraction.nfzOcr
   :members:
```

and the conf path would be this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
```

It's working anyway with the documentation creation, but I still would like to know what I'm doing wrong with the import.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
from helperfunc import dbDeleteRow, dbInsert, dbSelect
```

to

```
from .helperfunc import dbDeleteRow, dbInsert, dbSelect
```

That is the correct syntax for a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).